# rJava in Shiny on Ubuntu

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to run a Shiny app on my Ubutnu 16.04 server that uses`rJava` (to run `xlsx` and `gridGraphics`). I get the following error in the Shiny log:

```
Loading required package: rJava
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Warning: Error in : package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
Stack trace (innermost first):
    59: .getRequiredPackages2
    58: library
    57: custom_analysis [/srv/shiny-server/GiddyUpAnalysis/server.R#16]
    56: observerFunc [/srv/shiny-server/GiddyUpAnalysis/server.R#448]
     1: runApp
```

I had the same error when running R from the console as root and ubuntu but solved them with `sudo R CMD javareconf`, `R CMD javareconf`, and `unset JAVA_HOME`. So I tired changing to shiny and doing the same. Works for local user but sudo asks for a password which should be blank...

```
ubuntu@ip:~$ sudo -su shiny
shiny@ip:~$ R CMD javareconf
*** JAVA_HOME is not a valid path, ignoring
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_131
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/linux
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/../include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR


JAVA_HOME        : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/linux
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /usr/lib/R
/usr/lib/R/bin/javareconf: 406: /usr/lib/R/bin/javareconf: cannot create /usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf.new: Permission denied
*** cannot create /usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf.new
*** Please run as root if required.

shiny@ip:~$ sudo R CMD javareconf
[sudo] password for shiny:
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for shiny:
```

I have checked the properties of `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rJava/libs/rJava.so`:

```
ubuntu@ip:~$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root staff 352144 Jun 21 20:56 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
ubuntu@ip:~$ stat -c %a /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
775
```

I tried changing to `chmod 777` but same results.

I tried changing the `run_as` user in `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf` to `ubuntu` but got the same result. Tried it as `root` too and the app wouldn't load.

R 3.4.0
Ubuntu 16.04.2.

What am I missing?